# Vim write temporary info as :write does

Tags: vim

I have a macro which calls a function I defined in my vimrc

```
:function! DoStuff()
  :!mycommand
:end

map <C-p>i :call DoStuff()<CR>
```

When I press the macro keys I get right a shell with the output of mycommand and it works fine but I would like improve that.

I noticed that when I write a file (:w) a short message is displayed for short time in the command bar which says "File X written", I want to achieve the same result, when macro sequence is pressed I want check if the command went fine (checking the return code) and then display a message (such "Ok" or "Not Okay") as the :write command does.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think `:write` has nothing to do with temporary files. You should give another read on Vim documentation. If your question about how to redirect the output of a system command to the current buffer you could try something like `:put =system('mycommand')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Write external command output to a temporary file

#### via Vimscript functions

First, capture the output of the external command in a variable, whose contents can then be written to a (temporary) file via `writefile()`.

```
:let output = system('mycommand')
:call writefile(output, 'path/to/tempfile')
```

#### via scratch buffer

If you need to apply arbitrary commands to the captured contents, or need Vim to handle different file encodings, you have to use a buffer:

```
:new path/to/tempfile
:0read !mycommand
:write
:bdelete
```

#### via file redirection

This is the simplest approach when you need the output as-is:

```
:!mycommand > path/to/tempfile
```

### Check for command success and notify

After external command execution, the special variable `v:shell_error` contains exit status of the last shell command. You can test that to report a message to the user:

```
!mycommand
if v:shell_error != 0
    echohl ErrorMsg
    echomsg "The command failed"
    echohl None
else
    echomsg "The command succeeded"
endif
```

If you've used `system()` to execute the command, you also have the error message returned by it, and can include that in the notification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I am explained myself so badly that I rewrote the question.

Comment: @pedr0: That really didn't came across. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It is also possible to use `silent !mycommand` to hide the outuput of the external command (if you are on ms-windows silent won't hide the cmd.exe -- that could be achieved with `xolox#misc#os#exec()` from [vim-shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123)).